# Are transactions like big queries?

Tags: mysql, database, transactions, database-optimization

I know that in terms of efficiency it is better to have one big query instead of many small ones, as it is better to reduce the amount of connections with the database to the minimum (especially in context of intense network traffic).

So my question is, besides isolating and atomizing a set of database manipulations (and doing a roll-back if one of them fails) does a transaction *act* like a big query? I mean, if you need to do many database manipulations, can you wrap it in a transaction and turn it into a single big operation?

Comment: If the spirit of your question is "can I improve performance by using transactions?" then the answer is a resounding NO! Transactions give you many benefits, including atomicity of multiple operations, rollback ability, etc. But these features come at a cost, a performance cost.

Comment: @Asaph Are you sure about that ? It's very easy to create an example that benefits *hugely* from transactions; e.g. do 100 000 inserts, one SQL statement per insert, one transaction per SQL statement (this is often the default if you don't explicitly use transactions).  Repeat the test, but place 100 SQL statement inside a transaction. The one doing 100 inserts per transaction is going to be a lot faster than doing 1 insert per transaction, at least on all the DBMS's I've tested.

Comment: @nos That's interesting. I've seen benefit from batching inserts, for example with MySQL's multi-row insert statement (which I suppose would run in an implicit transaction). I've seen order of magnitude performance gains. It never occurred to me to try a transaction approach to achieve the batching effect. Makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if I understand what you're asking. You can think of a transaction as setting a checkpoint in the database history so if any of the individual operations within the transaction fails the database state can be restored to the checkpoint. That's a big simplification but conceptually that's how transactions work.

Within a transaction the individual queries are executed separately.

And it's not always better or more efficient to have "one big query instead of many small ones." That depends on what the queries are. It is more efficient to ask for a set of rows in one big query rather than ask for them one at a time. I've actually seen code that does this (pseudocode):

```
SELECT id FROM people WHERE ... ORDER BY lastname;

for each (id) {
    SELECT firstname, lastname, phone from people WHERE id = {id};
    ...
}
```

That would be a lot more efficient as

```
SELECT id, firstname, lastname, phone FROM people WHERE ... ORDER BY lastname;
```

Comment: As I understand it the question was not *"will it be faster?"* but *"will it be a single big operation?"*.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys, although I'm a bit confused here. Within a transaction are the individual queries are executed separately or are they all treated as a single query like @Tomalak said?

Comment: @John I did not say that. That's even logically impossible, If you think about it. What I said is that the operation becomes *atomic*, which means that it succeeds as a whole, or fails as a whole, no matter how many (or which) individual operations are part of a transaction. The DB server makes sure no other operation can interfere with the transaction and should an error occur, all affected changes are undone. If two tables need an update to stay consistent, a transaction makes sure the two updates either happen successfully for both tables, or not at all. That's what transactions are for.

Comment: @Tomalak I understand, I think it's safe to say then that the answer to my original question is no, transactions are not like a huge query but like many queries executed individually and treated like a whole. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

the problem with this approach is: you will lock some resources and it is bad for concurrency. and if you have one error in one query the rollback will be huge.

I try to avoid transactions and sometimes I need to implement some kind of compensatory transactions if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

> if you need to do many database manipulations, can you wrap it in a transaction and turn it into a single big operation

Yes. That operation will be atomic, just like a single row-update.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of disk I/O: Maybe (depending on how large the transaction is and a multitude of other factors).
In terms of network I/O, which you are asking about: **No**. Transactions are implemented on the server side.